# JasperReports flexible Template Design

Tags: jasper-reports

Is it possible to create one Flexible Template Design for different page size and orientation?

I have frame border with tables in header and footer.  But I can create tables only with fixed  width

In IReport templates collection I found same design templates for landscape & portrate orientation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate report template and report itself on runtime using JasperReports API depending on your report conditions.

Create `JasperDesign jasperDesign = new JasperDesign();`
and you can do anything with it in runtime. for example

```
 jasperDesign.setName("ReportDesign");
    jasperDesign.setPageWidth(595);
    jasperDesign.setPageHeight(842);
    jasperDesign.setColumnWidth(515);
    jasperDesign.setColumnSpacing(0);
    jasperDesign.setLeftMargin(40);
    jasperDesign.setRightMargin(40);
    jasperDesign.setTopMargin(30);
    jasperDesign.setBottomMargin(30);
    jasperDesign.addStyle(textStyles.getBoldStyle(11));
    jasperDesign.addStyle(textStyles.getNormalStyle(10));
    jasperDesign.addStyle(textStyles.getItalicStyle(11));
    jasperDesign.addStyle(textStyles.getCourierStyle(10));
```

Comment: For my user simpler to create design template xml file in IReport